# Removing Duplicates from a query

Tags: sql-server

So I have the following query

```
SELECT r.userId, r.programmeId, u.email, u.firstName, u.lastName, u.profileId, tblProgrammes.name, u.storeId, r.dateEnded AS lastPass, r.dateExpired
FROM tblUserRepeatHistory AS r INNER JOIN
tblUsers AS u ON r.userId = u.id INNER JOIN
tblProgrammes ON r.programmeId = tblProgrammes.id
WHERE (r.dateExpired IS NOT NULL) AND (u.storeId = @storeId)
GROUP BY r.userId, r.programmeId, u.email, u.firstName, u.lastName, u.profileId, tblProgrammes.name, u.storeId, r.dateEnded, r.dateExpired, r.id
HAVING (DATEDIFF(D, MAX(r.dateExpired), GETDATE() + 31) >= 0)
```

Which returns the following data

```
11 22 asdf@asdf.com store-mgr jamie2 1 Deli Food Service 1 5 04/02/2011 09:36:11 10/05/2011 09:36:11

11 22 asdf@asdf.com store-mgr jamie2 1 Deli Food Service 1 5 04/02/2011 09:36:11 10/05/2011 09:36:11

11 22 asdf@asdf.com store-mgr jamie2 1 Deli Food Service 1 5 11/05/2011 09:44:36 10/07/2011 09:44:36

11 23 asdf@asdf.com store-mgr jamie2 1 Deli Food Service 2 5 11/05/2011 10:12:50 16/06/2011 10:12:50
```

I basically only 1 record returned for each user and programme, where the most recently added one should be returned so i guess by MAX(dateExpired). So i.e this query should only return two records

```
11 22 asdf@asdf.com store-mgr jamie2 1 Deli Food Service 1 5 11/05/2011 09:44:36 10/07/2011 09:44:36
11 23 asdf@asdf.com store-mgr jamie2 1 Deli Food Service 2 5 11/05/2011 10:12:50 16/06/2011 10:12:50
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT DISTINCT` are the SQL keywords you'll need. `DISTINCT` causes the query to only return the columns that are different

Comment: Don't think that will do it, because some of the records are different but I still only 1 record returned for each user Id and Programme Id

Answer (score 0):

Remove r.dateExpired from GROUP BY clause and replace it with "MAX(r.dateExpired) as dateExpired" in select list.

Comment: Tried that, still getting more than 1 record back for each user and programme

Comment: Probably you need to do same changes with r.dateEnded field. It is actually quite easy to spot - look at results, which fields are different and do not group by these fields.

Comment: If I have understood the Q correctly, only r.userId and r.programmeId should be in the GROUP BY clause

Answer (score 0):

you can use cross apply

```
SELECT * FROM tblUsers as u CROSS JOIN tblProgrammes p
CROSS APPLY
(SELECT TOP 1 dateExpired FROM tblUserRepeatHistory
WHERE userId = u.id and programmeId = p.id
ORDER BY dateExpired desc
) as rr
```

in the co-related sub query you get the maximum dateExpired in tblUserRepeatHistory where meet the programme and the user,
cross apply is something like inner join, for nested queries and table-valued functions